# Change layout of emulator in Android

Tags: android, android-emulator

I'm newbie in Android application development. I just downloaded all SDks and Eclispe. Then I created sample project with the help of some online tutorials. On running the project for the first time it asked me to set virtual emulator and I then set some arbitrary values for layout (I guess 700), now when I run the project every time the emulator size is so big that it doesn't fit im my computer screen. 
How can I change the settings for emulator? also my emulator gets hanged and says not responding, any suggestion will be appreciate.
Apologies if the question is silly, I'm just trying out my hands at Android.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pramodtech... on Eclipse you can set the scaling factor from 0.1 to 3.

```
Go to Run --> Run Configurations... 
--> Target tab 
--> Scroll until you see Additional Emulator Command Line Options 
--> enter -scale <0.1 to 3> 
--> Apply
```

If you want to change the screen size:

```
Go to Window --> Android AVD Manager 
--> Virtual Devices Select AVD 
--> Select Edit 
--> Select Skin: Built-in HVGA (for 160) 
--> Edit AVD to save.
```

Comment: thanks, I could change screen size. I didn't understand setting scale? i tried but it gave error saying invalid command scale.

Comment: @Pramodtech  The system should automatically scale the AVD to fit your screen. Occasionally this is not enough on a laptop so there is an additional option -scale. So on my laptop system I added the emulator command line option -scale 0.9 You may need to scroll down on a laptop to even see the edit box to set the command line option!

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are starting an API level 11 or 12 emulator. This can be very slow to start. To fix the display size start the emulator from the SDK manager icon and select the option 'scale display to real size'

Comment: thanks NickT for quick help. I followed little different way. In Eclispe ->Window->Android SDK and AVD Manager->Virtual devices->I see existing device with platfor 1.6 & API level 4-> Start->Scale to real size display. But this does not change the size of emulator when I run my project, still shows old size emulator. any suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

You can close your emulator, open the Android AVD manager (by clicking its icon in the Eclipse toolbar), and then edit your AVD's resolution.

-A

P.S. AVD = Android virtual device